# Phone restores to certain status everytime it (re)boots

Tags: applications, files

I came across an Android phone which has a very strange phenomenon: it restores to certain status every time it boots or reboots.

Installed apps and saved files will disappear, and uninstalled apps and deleted files will come back after (re)booting.

I tried factory reset from settings and recovery, but neither worked.

It seems the phone is still, and no changes can be done to it.

I'm curious about how it became like this, and wonder if there is a way to solve it.

Comment: have you tried rooting the phone?

Comment: @pyker I tried rooting (succeeded as tool reported) but it return unroot after (re)booting, though I think the phenomenon has nothing to do with rooting.

Comment: I would try putting a different firmware on it such as cyanogenmod. If it still reverts, my guess would be a hardware related issue.